# When can GKZ setup encompass HMS?

Tags: homological-algebra, derived-categories, hypergeometric-functions, mirror-symmetry

Are there any instances when the Landau-Ginzburg superpotential describing the mirror of a smooth projective Fano variety $X_\Sigma$ is encompassed by a GKZ hypergeometric system? In some sense I am just asking what examples of (homological) mirror symmetry are GKZ, and what it means for a homological mirror to be GKZ. It seems to me that the Fukaya-Seidel category of vanishing cycles and thimbles for an exact Lefschetz fibration coming from a Landau-Ginzburg superpotential with a varying family of Laurent polynomials whose summands come from the primitive ray generators for $\Sigma$ is described by a "GKZ setup" coming from a dual triangulation of the Newton polytope of the corresponding Laurent polynomial for the mirror, considered as a hypersurface in $(\mathbb{C}^*)^n$ wherein the limit of a tropical amoeba gives a tropical skeleton. It seems like a similar setup, but I don't know how to formulate this. Is this tropical skeleton ever the $\mathcal{A}$-discriminant described by GKZ?

Does the adjective that a mirror is GKZ mean that the period integral is a GKZ hypergeometric integral? Or more generally that a theta function is hypergeometric in some way?